# PHP Form Works Correctly in Firefox, but not in IE and Chrome

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to create a form that will send to my email. The form works perfectly in Firefox, however, *it does not work in Chrome/Internet Explorer*. Hopefully someone can help!

*EDIT* What's happening is that my php is simply being displayed as text in the browser *EDIT*

HTML CODE:

```
   <form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform">
       <label for="myName">Name: </label>
       <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" />

       <label for="myEmail">E-mail: </label>
       <input type="email" name="myEmail" id="myEmail" />

       <label for="myNumber">Phone Number: </label>
       <input type="tel" name="myNumber" id="myNumber" />

       <label for="myComments">Comments: </label>
       <textarea name="myComments" id="myComments" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>

       <input id="mySubmit" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['myName'];
$field_email = $_POST['myEmail'];
$field_phone = $_POST['myNumber'];
$field_message = $_POST['myComments'];

$mail_to = 'alexandriadrugs@yahoo.com';
$subject = 'Message from '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to alexandriadrugs@yahoo.com');
        window.location = 'contact.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>`
```

Comment: Since PHP is a server-side language, the error, to me, must be occurring on the last part of your code. However, instead of printing a script, you may instead use php's `header` function, if you only want to redirect. You may also print something (like the alert) and delay the redirect, if you want the user to read something. Something like: `header('refresh: 10; url=contact.html');`

Comment: My issue here is that I do not know a lick of PHP. The PHP is borrowed from a buddy of mine. I only made minor changes to it to try and get it to work with my site. However, as I said before, it will only display in Firefox. So something has to be wrong with the PHP. It needs to be modified, I just don't know what is wrong/how to fix it.

Comment: Please remember we're not in front of your computer and need more information. Where exactly is the problem? you don't see the form? you don't get the email? you don't get the alert? the page don't redirect?  every answer can lead to different area.

Comment: Sorry, what's happening is my php is simply displaying as text in the browser.

Comment: @user3476787: are you running a Web Server or what? If it is displaying as a text I'm sorry but you should first **learn** what php is before **using** it.

Comment: I'm running it on my home computer with notepad++. (Run in Chrome, Run in Firefox, Run in IE, etc) I'm currently building a website and I just need a simple form for it. Also, while I agree that I should learn PHP, I'm just beginning web development and this is the first site I've ever created. No need to be insulting, it's frankly unwarranted and not necessary.

Comment: @user3476787 every programming language requires a compiler to run. A browser can compile html and javascript, but those are front-end languages. php is a back-end language that runs on the server and requires a compiler that will run it.

Comment: @Gil Ahh, that would make sense then. It seems that I probably need to upload this to a web server that supports PHP in order to test and see if it will work correctly. Firefox probably just displays the message that it has sent when it hasn't actually sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to google and type XAMP download.
2. Download and install the application
3. Go on C:/XAMP/htdocs and empty that folder
4. PASTE the files that your friend gave to you righ there
5. Make sure your file containing the form code that you posted here (on stackoverflow) is named index.html or index.php
6. Go on XAMP control panel and start apache
7. Open some web browser and type `http://`localhost

You should have your problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Firefox will run Php from the file directory while IE and Chrome will display them as plain text unless you specically tell them to run the file as the HTTP protocol. This may seem like a bug but they are infact doing a better job than Firfox by following the correct protocols being asked for:

OPEN FILE:
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/mypage.php

Request Webpage
http:// localhost/mypage.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you're not running a web server that supports PHP. The PHP code won't be recognised that way, and it will be displayed like it's html.